# How do I determine the distance of an object if the acceleration is constantly changing?

Tags: calculus, dynamical-systems

I am investigating a pendulum's movement and I am trying to create a proof, or an equation that describes the movement. My problem is that as the pendulum is falling the angle between the force of gravity and the string is constantly changing and as that angle changes so does the acceleration acting upon the bob (the mass on the end of the string). I am stomped as how I can create an equation which describes the distance the bob has traveled as it falls.

**My question:** How do I determine the distance of an object with a constantly changing acceleration?

**Diagram:** [image: My considerations]

Comment: Check out [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)). The way to describe it is by means of a *differential equation*, well-suited for these situations. Although its exact solution is rather complicated (see Legendre solution), it is easy to get a well-known approximation by $\sin(\theta)\approx\theta$.

Comment: How is it that $\sin\theta \approx \theta$? Can you direct me to a resource for understanding this approximation?

Comment: For instance here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series, and the graphic example is sin.

Comment: @Klik as dkuper said, this comes from the Taylor series of sine. This approximation is adequate only when $\theta$ is in radians and quite small. An easier but strongly related problem is describing the motion of a mass-spring system, also by means of differential equations.